# How to create 3D Surface charts with highcharts alternatives?

Tags: html, vb.net, highcharts

I should create a 3D-surface charts.
I would like to obtain something similar to the picture attached below - that picture was obtained using Microsoft Excel:

[image: 3D-chart sample]\

I should automatically process some data to obtain similar charts, moreover it would be nice if I could let the end user the possibility to rotate them (but this is not necessary, it's a plus).

I thought to use highcharts, but I didn't find any example of surface charts.

I would like to know if it is possible to create 3D-surface charts using highcharts?

If it weren't possible could you suggest some alternative to reach the same result (using an HTML extension or even a Visual Studio API for a VB.net form application), please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello, explain please - what is "highcharts" are you mean?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello, with Highcharts I mean this tool https://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: Probably not the appropiate place for this question.  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to be asking for recommendations.  There are plenty of 3rd party charting tools out there, it's really up to you to evaluate what works for your context and really questions about the capability of these should be directed to the developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts provides only limited 3D support to charts, but you can try to build a surface chart with it.

- with dense distributed columns: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rngbd69x/
- polygon with triangle shapes: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nf3yutpx/

  ```
  series: [{
    ...,
    data: [
      [0, 0, 0],
      [0, 4, 2],
      [3, 1, 1],
      null,
      ...
    ]
  }]
  ```

Performance can be an issue in both cases, but you can improve it by removing the rotate feature and reducing number of points.

---

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/3d-charts

Comment: Thank you for your answer! At the end I opted for a 3D bubble chart, because, since I had a lot of point, the result was similar to a surface.